# How to give irregular shape cropping in android

Tags: android

I have requirement to crop the image in irregular shape. i saw the ios application, they have done it using BezierPath, is there any thing which work same as BezierPath in android, please suggest some alternative method how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what kind of crop you need and who is preparing the crop shape? The user or the developer?
One option is to prepare whatever crop shape you want in a black and white image and use that image as a mask for your image.
If there are some functions in Android to draw irregular shape into an image, you can use those to create your image mask.
(You can do a lot of stuff with OpenGLES, but I assume you want something simpler).

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is masking. By doing masking you can cut irregular shapes in the image. 
Check this [library](https://github.com/worldsproject/android-jigsaw-puzzle-library) . You can also checkout cocos2d game engine which supports opengl masking functions.